# ORA-06512 when creating a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger for an existing table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "AD_EDGE_FORECAST_PRODUCTS" 
AFTER DELETE ON "EDGE_FORECAST_PRODUCTS" FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE EDGE_FORECAST
        SET PRODUCTS_VCE = CASE WHEN PRODUCTS_VCE IS NULL
                           THEN NULL
                           ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(PRODUCTS_VCE, :NEW.PRODUCT, ''), '::', ':') END,

            PRODUCTS_VCP = CASE WHEN PRODUCTS_VCP IS NULL
                           THEN NULL
                           ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(PRODUCTS_VCP, :NEW.PRODUCT, ''), '::', ':') END,

            PRODUCTS_GRC = CASE WHEN PRODUCTS_GRC IS NULL
                           THEN NULL
                           ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(PRODUCTS_GRC, :NEW.PRODUCT, ''), '::', ':') END,

            PRODUCTS_PLM = CASE WHEN PRODUCTS_PLM IS NULL
                           THEN NULL
                           ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(PRODUCTS_PLM, :NEW.PRODUCT, ''), '::', ':') END,

            PRODUCTS_MDM = CASE WHEN PRODUCTS_MDM IS NULL
                           THEN NULL
                           ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(PRODUCTS_MDM, :NEW.PRODUCT, ''), '::', ':') END
    WHERE ID = :NEW.ID
END;
```

But when I try to run this code, I get the following results:

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", line 581
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", line 567
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2127
```

What is the problem here?

Did I forget something basic/stupid about the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semi-colon at the end of the SQL statement (ie "WHERE ID = :NEW.ID;" )